# org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: No results returned by the query

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot

hey everyone am trying to insert data in a table using `@Query` annotation in my spring boot app am getting a postgres Exception :

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException:  No results returned by the query
```

this is my code :

this is the repository

```
@Query(value="INSERT INTO \"FCT_BY_DEV\"(\"IdDev\", \"IdFonction\") VALUES (?, ?) ",nativeQuery=true)
public String isertfonctionstodev(int dev,int fonction);
```

this is the controller :

```
@RequestMapping(value="/function/insert", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String insererfonctions (int dev,int fonction){
    System.out.println("dev="+dev+"fonction="+fonction);
     fonctionRepository.isertfonctionstodev(dev, fonction);
     System.out.println("********");
     return "aaa";
 }
```

am using this service by $http in angularJs

```
$http.post("/function/insert?dev="+$scope.id+"&fonction="+$scope.idf);
```

and finaly this is the server log

```
dev=16006fonction=14
Hibernate: INSERT INTO "FCT_BY_DEV"("IdDev", "IdFonction") VALUES (?, ?) 
 2016-04-27 16:52:03.204  WARN 7036 --- [nio-8080-exec-2]    o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 02000
 2016-04-27 16:52:03.204 ERROR 7036 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Aucun résultat retourné par la requête.
```

the data is correct and i tried the same query with the same value and it worked why posgres is generating this exception and how can i fixed , thanks to any help

Comment: not sure how does your ORM work, but `INSERT` query is not supposed to return anything (like a recordset) unless you use a `RETURNING` clause. Seems like your ORM expects a recordset.

Comment: Your method return type is  `String`. What are you expecting here? Shouldn't it be `void`?

Comment: i just edited before i posted the question i thought maybe i could get the result as String it will work but it didn't neither in void or in String

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I think modifying queries must be annotared with an extra

```
@Modifying
```

Answer (score 16):

This should solve your issue:

```
@Transactional
@Modifying(clearAutomatically = true)
@Query(value="update policy.tbl_policy set ac_status = 'INACTIVE' where pol_id = :policyId and version_no = :version_no and ac_status = 'ACTIVE'", nativeQuery=true)
public void updateExistingRowbyId(@Param("policyId") Long pol_id, @Param("version_no") Long version_no);
```

Without @Transactional annotation, following errors may occur: 
**javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete query**

Comment: Why is `clearAutomatically = true` in your answer? Is it required?